# How to limit GSON parsing to the first 100 Array objects?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I have this code which works well with small JSON data.

But I am currently working on a huge JSON file, and I want to parse only the first 100 objects.

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Reader reader=API.getData(testURL);

            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DoctorBean>>(){}.getType();
            beanPostArrayList = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(reader, listType);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            populateTable();
        }

    }.execute();
```

API Class

```
public class API {
private static Reader reader=null;
public static Reader getData(String SERVER_URL) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SERVER_URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
        } 

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return reader;
}
```

}

Do you have any suggestions...

Comment: I think, that is not possible (but I'm not sure), but generally good practice is saying, that this should be limited on server side:
1. user will use less bandwith
2. It will use less resources on app side to proceed with it

Comment: It is possible but you have to implement json parsing yourself. This is only your specific use case and as @MateuszPryczkowski mentioned it is better to limit it on server side

Comment: @EugenMartynov - he asked about making this with Gson, and there I still  think, that it is not possible (and still I'm not sure of it)

Comment: Missed most important **GSON** requirement. It is hacky, but I would override `InputStreamReader` and return end of array symbol after 100 elements. So he could keep current setup